# Removing quotes from doskey macro (export=set)

Tags: cmd, doskey

I'm trying to remove incoming quotes for a doskey macro that will let me use "export" as "set". Here's what I have:

```
doskey export=set $*
```

Except when I run with the following:

```
export VAR="value"
```

I end up with:

```
VAR="value"
```

vs what I wanted:

```
VAR=value
```

I think I have to write a little method of sorts to 'clean' the input to set but I don't know how to do that - something like "for (var1=var2) do set var1=~var2", but I can't get anything like that to work.

Help!

Comment: There is not `export` command. In what way are you using `export`? If you want to set the value of an environment variable, use `SET "VAR=value"

Comment: doskey.exe creates console aliases. By default it creates aliases that are in effect whenever "cmd.exe" does a cooked read from the console (i.e. calls `ReadConsole` or `ReadFile` on a console input handle). Aliases can also be created specifically for other executables such as python.exe. A console alias works by replacing text that's matched at the start of a line. It can't be used anywhere else in an input command that's read from the console. It also can't be used in a batch script. So it's really of limited value.

Comment: The console allows parameterizing the rest of the white-space delimited command line as `$1` up to `$9`, as well as `$*` for the entire command-line after the alias itself. You can use `$*` in the replacement string, e.g. in a `for` loop or whatever. But bear in mind that CMD will literally read the `for` loop from the console, so it has to be valid syntax for an interactive command line. It's not as if it's being evaluated like a function or calling an `export.bat` script.

Comment: You'll need to filter out those quotes before you execute the `export` statement (to avoid the complications accurately noted by eryksun).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it with a for loop too, but this is easier:

```
set ORIGARGS=%*
set ARGCOPY=
:copyargs
    set "ARGCOPY=%ARGCOPY% %~1"
    shift
    if not [%1]==[] goto:copyargs
```

ie. (line-by-line)

1. save the original `%*` since we're going to destroy it.
2. prepare a variable (`ARGCOPY`) to put the converted arguments into
3. label (target of goto in line 6)
4. append the first argument `%1` to `ARGCOPY`, but remove quotes (`%~1`)
5. `shift` all arguments to the left one space (i.e. what was `%2` becomes `%1`, etc.)
6. if we've reached the end of the arguments then `%1` has no value, otherwise `goto` line 3, where the `:copyargs` label is located.

when you're done `%ARGCOPY%` will contain the parameters without quotes.

Comment: Wow, thanks and I appreciate the explanation of how that works. Now, how do I insert that into a doskey macro?

Comment: `export %ARGCOPY%` if `export` is your doskey macro.

Comment: Please remember to upvote all answers that were helpful, and select the answer that best answered your question. This will help future visitors, and to give me points :-)